# Arduino Uno replace with Atmega8

Tags: arduino, programming

Can I take out the Atmage328 and replace with a Atega8 for programing instead of trying to program using a breadboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atmega8 has a smaller memory but should be a pin-compatible replacement to the Atmega328 for most purposes. Note, however, that the Atmega8 does have a smaller memory, and also a few registers are different, so some might not work, but most common ones should work just fine.

In terms of the Arduino environment, you'll need to do two things:

- First burn the corresponding Arduino bootloader (the one named "Arduino NG or older w/ ATmega8" in the Arduino IDE) onto your Atmega8 chip. To burn the bootloader onto the Atmega8 chip, you'll have to either use an AVR/ICSP programmer or use another Arduino board as the ISP.
- And when you are uploading sketches, be sure to select the correct board (again, the one named "Arduino NG or older w/ ATmega8") from the menu in the Arduino IDE.

EDIT:
Read these documents to understand how to use a second Arduino as an ISP (In-circuit Serial Programmer) in order to burn the bootloader onto a new chip: [First](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-Your-Arduino-Into-an-ISP/), and [Second](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP), and [Third](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard)

Comment: Yes so Im using 2 Uno's I repalced one with the atmega8 and just trying to sort out the cables. Do you know what ones to link from and to? Thanks

Comment: @MrMen: Added that info at the end of my Answer.